# 3+ Multitouch points in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to simulate gestures with 3 or more touchpoints on iOS Simulator. I know about creating two touchpoints with alt + click and alt + shift + click. Is there any way to generate 3 or more touchpoints while using the simulator?

Xcode 9.4.1
Simulator 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently supported.

If this is something you'd like to see, please do file an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: It absolutely answers the question. The answer may be wrong, but it is definitely an answer to the question.

Comment: @robmayoff I wrote the Simulator's virtual digitizer support. You can consider my answer the authority on the subject.